# How to patch kernel to reduce VTIME gap for uart termios API?

Tags: linux, kernel, tty, serial-port, serial-console

I need help to find a kernel patch to get a VTIME from tty termios API lower than 100ms, in order to decrease gap inter char. It blocks read syscall until VTIME timeout.

Function n_tty_read() is the  patch entry point :
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/n_tty.c#L2131

[image: source code to patch]

Is there someone to advise me? I have to use non-canonical mode (without framing protocol, no ascii, no break). And VMIN param is null because all messages length are variables.
The solution to poll each char is too expensive with a multiple uart system and implied multiple process context switches.

Extract termios manual:
VTIME Timeout in **deciseconds** for noncanonical read (TIME). https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html

A Linux kernel patch is necessary...
Is it better to divide HZ with a greater value ? Or to set global HZ to a smaller value ?

Microsoft Windows Serial API is able to configure until 1ms but not Linux. So Windows is better for raw Serial port processing.
**ReadIntervalTimeout** : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddser/ns-ntddser-_serial_timeouts

[image: in non canonical mode, the read buffer will only accept 4095 chars]

Comment extract "in non-canonical mode ... **only accept 4095 char**", I think problem is here, perhaps it is why read_wait queue is not woke up.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/n_tty.c#L1667

Comment: Please ask a full question here. The question you linked to was closed and might be deleted at any point. The one sentence you added to your question here is useless for understanding of what you need to do.

Comment: the question you link to is also not very good. It throws around a lot of very questionable assumptions, shows a screenshot of a potentially totally unrelated source code, and doesn't even explain what you need to do. Start your question here with: "I have {precise description of the problem you have} while trying to {explain exactly what you're trying to do, from a higher-up perspective}".

Comment: Ok Marcus, question is done

Comment: you sadly didn't address the things that I asked you to: none of what you write indicates *why* you need a kernel patch. You just say you need it. Please tell us what you want to *do*, what doesn't *work*; why you think you need a kernel patch. You also said that polling is out of question because it's "expensive", but it's really not, especially not at the rates you seem to be referring to (you didn't actually tell us the rate). So, this is all still very confusing, and it seems to me you're mostly jumping to conclusions.

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/time/timer.c#L2099     schedule_timeout() takes timeout value in jiffies...

Comment: that is just another link, to **completely** unrelated code. Nothing like an explanation of why *you* think *you* need a kernel patch. **nothing in that indicates you need a kernel patch**. You need to explain to us why you think you need one, if you want us to be able to tell you *how* and *what* to patch.

Comment: Marcus, this is a termios limitation. 100ms to wait blocked for a read syscall is too long with a message length average of 10ms long.

Comment: so, don't `read` while there's not enough data available; that's what `select`, `epoll` etc is for. And `termios` is a userland library function, not a kernel functionality, so *another* indication that fiddling in the kernel is not going to take you far.

Comment: Honestly, this could all be very easy, you might not need to patch anything, and you could be done in a few minutes, but we can't know that. you simply don't tell us what you want to do, from a higher-up perspective. We can't guess that, so this all remains mysterious.

Comment: In non-canonical mode, we need more reactivity to wake up the userspace software when RX message end. Select() function locks the fd until VTIME too.

Comment: I give up and vote to close your question as unclear. you don't *want* to tell us what you want to achieve, but have very fixed ideas what you need to do. Fine, but that's not a basis for asking a question.

Comment: Marcus, Linux never replaces modem system with non-canonical protocol. That is the historical problem. What perspective you want more? I will patch sorry by myself.

Comment: I must admit that it always seems a futile exercise: demanding an OP share more information because you want to answer a question other than the one they have asked. Voting to leave open because it is absolutely clear what this OP wants even if there is an outstanding question of **why** they want it.

Comment: https://youtu.be/g4sZUBS57OQ?feature=shared The TTY Layer: the Past, Present, and Future (Greg Kroah-Hartman, Linux Foundation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To propose a patch that keeps kernel API compatibility, I think a diversion solution is primary possible: It is to use VEOF paramater value (unsigned char value unused) of CANON mode to tune VTIME (add a division factor to timeout value before appling schedule_timeout function), which will be applied to NON-CANON mode read function.

Use VEOF value which is unused in non-canon mode:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/tty.h#L39

Apply division here: for example, if VEOF value differs from default value then apply to reduce VTIME timeout.
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/n_tty.c#L2196

Comment: The TTY Layer: the Past, Present, and Future (Greg Kroah-Hartman, Linux Foundation). https://youtu.be/g4sZUBS57OQ?feature=shared

Answer (score 1):

> I need help to find a kernel patch to get a VTIME from tty termios API lower than 100ms, ...
>
> A Linux kernel patch is necessary...

Such a patch to the kernel is ill-advised because it would change the userspace API. Linux strives to maintain a consistent API, and the patch you ask for would likely break existing applications.

Even if such a patch to the kernel didn't change the API, it's not likely to be reliable and achieve your unstated goal(s). You cannot or should not rely solely on VMIN and VTIME settings to detect time-separated messages.

If the UART utilizes a FIFO to buffer incoming data, then that hardware buffer obscures the intercharacter spacing that the software can detect. Similarly when the UART driver is using DMA to store the received data, intercharacter timing will be obscured.

The termios handling is at least a full layer above the UART device driver. The termios layer simply does not see the same timing information that as was on the wire after the bytes are handled/buffered by the UART and its driver.

---

> Microsoft Windows Serial API is able to configure until 1ms but not Linux. So Windows is better for raw Serial port processing.

If you think Windows is better suited for your application, then you should use it. But be forewarned that what is advertised is not necessarily what you'll get. That Windows API merely *advertises* the specification of a timeout with millisecond *precision*. That doesn't mean you will actually obtain such *accuracy*. For instance, there are warnings that:

> Time-out intervals are measured relative to the system clock, and **the accuracy of the time-out measurement is limited by the granularity of the system clock**. As a result, **a time-out can occur between one system clock tick earlier and one tick later than the specified time-out interval**, depending on where exactly the start and end times of this interval fall between system clock ticks. **Time-outs might occur even later** if system clock interrupt processing is delayed by interrupt processing for other devices. If a specified time-out interval is close to or smaller than the period between system clock ticks, **the time-out might occur immediately, with no delay**.

---

> I think problem is here, perhaps it is why read_wait queue is not woke up.

No, you persist in looking in the wrong place.
As I previously tried to point out to you (by referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152926/parsing-time-delimited-uart-data?noredirect=1&lq=1)), the reliable solution requires a timer to detect an idle UART receiver. However, even when the UART hardware implements a receiver timeout, (in two Linux drivers that I reviewed) the feature is only used to abort the current/active DMA operation.

Since a receiver timeout has (possibly) detected the end of a time-separated message, this event/information needs to be conveyed to the termios layer when the UART driver passes the received data. This is the missing piece of information that termios needs for a new variation of the `VMIN > 0` and `VTIME > 0` raw mode. Instead of termios checking for the intercharacter timeout, in this new variation the UART driver needs to indicate that timeout event with the received data.
That's not a trivial kernel patch.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, I found some explainations and I concluded that we are faced to an **API obsolecence** that implied to be bypassed by CPUs overconsumption.

The VTIME timeout granularity was **historically defined** as the unit of inter-byte gap (POSIX defined VTIME=100ms).
The currently inter-byte gap used by Linux still corresponds to a serial line of **110 bauds** ([one hundred and ten](https://lucidar.me/fr/serialib/most-used-baud-rates-table/)).
But nowadays, for example with a serial line of 115200 bauds, a byte TX duration is ~100 µs (micro second).

[Alan Cox : RE: termios VMIN and **VTIME behavior**](https://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0511.2/2455.html)

> Its pretty well defined. It was designed to optimise block serial
> operations (uucp and the like)
>
> VMIN - number of bytes you expect this packet VTIME - when to give up
> waiting
>
> **The form 0, VTIME also being used to do polling on old SYSV that
> lacked select/poll**

[POSIX 2007 June §11.1.7 Non-Canonical Mode Input Processing](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n4217.pdf)

> In non-canonical mode input processing, input bytes are not assembled
> into lines, and erase and kill processing shall not occur. The values
> of the MIN and TIME members of the c_cc array are used to determine
> how to process the bytes received. POSIX.1-200x does not specify
> whether the setting of O_NONBLOCK takes precedence over MIN or TIME
> settings. Therefore, if O_NONBLOCK is set, read() may return
> immediately, regardless of the setting of MIN or TIME. Also, if no
> data is available, read() may either return 0, or return −1 with errno
> set to [EAGAIN]. MIN represents the minimum number of bytes that
> should be received when the read() function returns successfully. **TIME
> is a timer of 0.1 second granularity that is used to time out bursty
> and short-term data transmissions.** If MIN is greater than {MAX_INPUT},
> the response to the request is undefined.

[The GNU C Library Reference Manual, for version 2.37, §17.4.10 **Noncanonical Input**](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Noncanonical-Input.html)

> Macro: int VTIME
> This is the subscript for the TIME slot in the c_cc
> array. Thus, termios.c_cc[VTIME] is the value itself.
>
> The TIME slot is only meaningful in noncanonical input mode; **it
> specifies how long to wait for input before returning, in units of 0.1
> seconds.** [...]
>
> MIN is zero but TIME has a nonzero value:
> In this case,
> read waits for time TIME for input to become available; the
> availability of a single byte is enough to satisfy the read request
> and cause read to return. When it returns, it returns as many
> characters as are available, up to the number requested. If no input
> is available before the timer expires, read returns a value of zero.

[2005 The SCO Group, Inc. § **Non-canonical mode input processing**](http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/SDK_sysprog/TDC_Non-CanonicalModeInProc.html)

> 1. (MIN>0, TIME>0).
>
> Because TIME>0, it serves as **an inter-byte timer** activated on
> receipt of the first byte of data, and reset on receipt of each byte
> of data.  MIN and TIME interact as follows:
>
> - As soon as a byte of data is received, the **inter-byte timer starts** (remember that the timer is reset on receipt of each byte).
> - If MIN bytes of data are received before the **inter-byte timer expires**, the read completes successfully.
> - If **the inter-byte timer expires** before MIN bytes of data are received, the read transfers any bytes received up until then.
>
> When TIME expires, a read transfers at least one byte of data because
> the **inter-byte timer is enabled** if and only if a byte of data was
> received. A program using this case must wait for at least one byte of
> data to be read before proceeding. In case (MIN>0, TIME>0), a read
> blocks until receiving a byte of data activates MIN and TIME, or a
> signal interrupts the read. Thus, the read transfers at least one byte
> of data.
>
> [...]
>
> 3. (MIN=0, TIME>0).
>
> Because MIN=0, **TIME no longer serves as an inter-byte timer**, but
> now serves as a read-timer activated when a read is processed (in
> canon). A read completes successfully as soon as any  bytes of data
> are received or the read-timer expires. A read does not  transfer any
> bytes of data if the read-timer expires. If the  read-timer does not
> expire, a read completes successfully if and only  if some bytes of
> data are received.    In case (MIN=0, TIME>0), the read does not block
> indefinitely waiting for a  byte of data. If no bytes of data are
> received within TIME*0.10 seconds after  the read starts, it returns 0
> having read no data. If the buffer holds data when a read starts, the
> read-timer starts as if it received data immediately.  MIN and TIME
> are useful when a program can assume that data is not available after
> a TIME interval and other processing can be done before data is
> available.

Comment: youtu.be/g4sZUBS57OQ?feature=shared The TTY Layer: the Past, Present, and Future (Greg Kroah-Hartman, Linux Foundation)